# How to get the eduroam network settings right on Linux? With that CA certificate, and without the installer from the eduroam website?

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, authentication, certificate, wireless-networking

Tried to follow an eduroam guide on a university site. That you can download the public installer from http://www.eduroam.org/, choose the university, and that is all. For Linux, this was a Python file which I had to start with `python eduroam-linux-xyz.py`, and it installs to `~/.config/cat_installer`, but this did not get eduroam to work.

[image]

[image]

Network Manager configuration failed, but we may generate a WPA_supplicant configuration file if you wish:

[image]

I entered my user id, or was the mail needed here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

"Installation successful", but I still had to enter the same network settings as below, and the internet did not work:

> The WPA-EAP configuration (more pricesely WPA/EAP-TTLS-PAP) requires following items:

```
SSID: eduroam  
Encryption: WPA Enterprise | WPA2 Enterprise (recommended)
EAP method: TTLS
Key: TKIP | AES (recommended)
Authentification: PAP
Anonymous identity: anonymous@home-institute.de
Identity: username@home-institute.de
```

If you enter these settings, you are asked for a CA (certificate authority) certificate, which is not listed in that guide (why not???).

This CA certificate can be found at `/etc/ssl/certs/T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem`, no need to download, something I had to fish from [SSL Certificate Location on UNIX/Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux) and [Eduroam requires installation of a CA Certificate - can they decrypt TLS traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229645/eduroam-requires-installation-of-a-ca-certificate-can-they-decrypt-tls-traffic).

[image]

If I then entered the rest of the settings, it still did not work, and I also tried the class_3 certificate like here, since class_2 might be outdated:

[image]

How to eduroam? So that it just works? Meaning, just having it, the internet?

I have Linux Mint, but this should be the same on all Linux OS.

Comment: I don't think serverfault is the correct place for this Q&A. It's far more suited at unix.SE or SuperUser SE.

Comment: @vidarlo Right, now that you say it. I chose Server Fault only since two links that helped were from Security and Server Fault Stack Exchange. I have flagged this to be moved to Super User since it is not a purely Linux question either (you will have the same thing to fix if you are on Windows, only the screenshots will not be the same).

Comment: Yes, I agree that SuperUser is probably the best place for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Q/A was not about what changes from network setup to network setup, but about the world-wide default eduroam network settings of:

There cannot be a world-wide default for the CA certificate, as it isn't used for connecting to the eduroam network itself – it is for connecting to *your institution's* EAP server specifically. (In other words, the CA certificate setting belongs to the specific "outer authentication" method such as PEAP or EAP-TTLS that your institution uses. The TLS handshake happens *inside* PEAP/TTLS.)

The **only** global requirement is that the "anonymous identity" field (aka "outer identity") must be in `user@domain` format, and the domain must match your home organization's domain – that's how eduroam routes the EAP requests towards the home organization.

(The eduroam network does not validate the outer username, however, so it's typical to specify `anonymous@the.domain` or even just `@the.domain` as the outer identity – hence "anonymous identity".)

The *inner* identity field, on the other hand, is completely invisible to the visited organization or to eduroam as a whole – it is sent encrypted within the EAP TLS tunnel to your home organization and validated there. Because of that, it cannot have a "world-wide default" format either; it's up to each organization to decide what it accepts.

> There is a mistake in the entries of the settings above. As a Username, you have to enter your full email, not just the username. This was also in the guide, but can be misunderstood in the settings.

Some organizations accept usernames without a @domain suffix (typically if they use the same RADIUS servers for other purposes besides eduroam), while other organizations deliberately reject such usernames, as it almost always indicates that the user forgot to enter a @domain at all (i.e. their "outer/anon. identity" field is missing one as well, and such a configuration would stop working as soon as the user visited another organization). Generally you should always include the domain.

It is possible that either a) the guide was written by someone whose organization did not have a @domain requirement (at the time), or b) the guide was written with Eduroam CAT in mind, which adds the domain automatically.

> If you enter these settings, you are asked for a CA (certificate authority) certificate, which is not listed in that guide (why not???).

Because many such guides date back to when WPA-EAP clients would default to *no verification at all* – i.e. it would still work without a CA specified; the UI wouldn't indicate anything about it being insecure; so specifying the correct CA was effort that most students wouldn't go through anyway.

Additionally, your home organization is using a *public* CA, so it's not very useful to specify it here anyway (as there's nothing that would prevent any other customer of that CA from using literally any random HTTPS certificate to perform a MITM attack).

What the tutorial should have suggested is using system CAs but specifying a domain to match against the EAP server's "leaf" certificate (similar to how the URL is matched against an HTTPS certificate). Unfortunately, the NetworkManager GUI in your screenshot is *also* old and doesn't offer this as an option – you would need to specify the domain through CLI. Eduroam CAT does this automatically though.

Comment: Your answer sheds light on quite a few blind spots, the blindest might be that you always have to fear the worst: that you might deal with outdated guides and old graphical user interfaces although you just click on the latest links and use the latest Linux Mint and check an official eduraom page. What is more, I would still not know how to set this up with the Eduroam CAT, but that was not the question, and I am glad that someone cares to check this Q/A on such a level. The only question left: "Why me?" :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the entries of the settings above. As a *Username*, you have to enter your full email, not just the username. This was also in the guide, but can be misunderstood in the settings.

Do not take *T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem* as I tried above. With that, my internet worked only for some 10m. I needed to take the *Class_2* certificate again to get it work.

[image]

Mind that the login can be just the student number 123456, and not the full mail 123456@uni-myuni.xyz that you enter as the username of the settings.

Mind that this is just one eduroam network setup of one university. Others can have other entries at:

- Security,
- Authentication, or
- Inner authentication.

The Q/A was not about what changes from network setup to network setup, but about the world-wide default eduroam network settings of:

- Anonymous identity
- CA certificate
- Username (pattern)

Comment: This answer seem ot would be very specific to the network configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound Made a remark on that, split into eduroam world-wide default and what is set by the university.